# Getting month in a string format

Tags: android

I want to show the date in format 22-Apr-2012.
I am using this code:

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        sdf.applyPattern("dd MMM yyyy");
        Date x = new Date(time.year,time.month,time.monthday);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(x));
```

But i am getting o/p as:
22 apr 3912.
I want to know why it is showing 3912 in place of 2012.

Comment: use dd-MM-yyyy. I think the problem is because of the delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) for Date class. It starts from year 1900 so in this constructor you must provide the date - 1900. But this constructor is deprecated so my advice is to start using Calendar object for your date related operations.
 for Java.da

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
String dateresult = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    String currentDateStr = dateformate.format(currentDate.getTime());
    Log.i("Infoe ", " " + currentDateStr.toString());       
    System.out.println("Current date is :  " + currentDateStr);
    ////=== OR

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    sdf.applyPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    Date x = new Date(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900,
            currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Log.i("Infoe ", " " + sdf.format(x));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(x));
```

its 3912 bcz ...date is setted like...
Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date) or GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date).
as per GregorianCalendar

i think use of calendar is gd as date is deprecated...
nd for date format use dd-MMM-yyyy no dd-MM-yyyy bcz you want month first 2 chars...
[For date Format](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html)